# playing an mp3 into a voice channel with discord.py

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a text-to-speech bot for people to use in no-mic-chats to speak into voice channels. I found other articles explaining this but most of them show the windows `ffmpeg` version but I am on a Mac. this is my code so far:

```
@bot.command()
async def speak(ctx, message):
    tts = gtts.gTTS(message, lang="en")
    tts.save("text.mp3")
    if ctx.guild.voice_client:
        vc = ctx.guild.voice_client
    else:
        voice_channel = get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name="Voice Lounge")
        vc = await voice_channel.connect()
    vc.play(source='text.mp3')
```

This gives me the error:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.`

Some people said to specify the FFMPEG.exe file but I do not see that. I downloaded the FFMPEG git from `git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg`

but I still get the error. other articles said to specify the executable but I can't find any `ffmpeg.exe` which I have to specify the path for.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/624562/1244261) explains how to install ffmpeg on Mac OS X. Does it help?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón no i still have the same problem

Comment: But you installed ffmpeg, right? Because the error message suggests it is not installed. So, after the installation, check that you can execute it in a terminal (e.g. `ffmpeg -version`) and if its directory is included in the `PATH` environment variable.